# Display List of Date Selected in Vaadin?

Tags: java, date, vaadin

Requirement:
have two dateFields which help select the start date and the end date.
The list of dates between that range should be displayed in a Table.

Help me with a solution for vaadin 7.

```
 public List<Date> getDatesBetween(final Date date1, final Date date2) {
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar() {{
            set(Calendar.YEAR, date1.getYear());
            set(Calendar.MONTH, date1.getMonth());
            set(Calendar.DATE, date1.getDate());
        }};

        while (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != date2.getYear() && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) != date2.getMonth() && calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) != date2.getDate()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            dates.add(new Date(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)));
        }

        return dates;
    }
```

This list is then displayed using :

```
    table=new Table("Employee dates!");
    table.removeAllItems();

   /// ...... within the loop 
    table.addItem();
  /// ...... within the loop 

 NOTE: an alternative way of getting the list of dates is appreciated.
```

Comment: i tried using the calender  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar() and set the year month  and date to a list of dates, and created a while loop : while (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != date2.getYear() && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) != date2.getMonth() && calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) != date2.getDate())                         and this goes in a function which will return this list of dates and add it to the table.

Comment: Please edit your question and write into your whole code, it is easier to read!

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood correctly you want to put in a table the list of the dates (day by day i suppose) between two dates.
You could do something like

```
public List<Date> getDatesBetween(final Date date1, final Date date2) {
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date1);

    //dates.add(date1); //use it if you need the first day
    while(c.getTime().compareTo(date2) < 0) { //date1 is lesser than date2, use <= if you need the last day
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dates.add(c.getTime());
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Now to put those value properly in a table, since are not a pure "item"s

```
Table tableDates = new Table("Dates from ... to ...");
tableDates.setSizeFull();
tableDates.setImmediate(true);
tableDates.addContainerProperty("date", Date.class, null);
tableDates.setColumnHeader("date", "Date");
```

And then for each date you can do

```
Object[] tableRow = new Object[] {date}; //date is a Date object..you can merge this in the "getDatesBetween" method above
tableDates.addItem(tableRow , null); //null -> autogenerated id
```

Comment: I think your while statement is an infinite loop, the date1 is never changed.

Comment: Good point..i should have used "c.getTime()". I'm gonna correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the Date class methods are deprecated (and misleading).
The `getYear()` javadoc writes: *the year represented by this date, minus 1900.*
Furthermore you have to replace `&&` with `||` in the while statement expression.

My suggestion:

```
public static List<Date> getDatesBetween(final Date date1, final Date date2) {
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

    Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    while (cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) != cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            || cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) != cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            || cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) != cal2.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dates.add(cal1.getTime());
    }

    return dates;
}
```